# How do I fill a material dropdownlist in angular 7 from my c# web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, angular7

I am new to angular and trying to figure out how to bind a dropdownlist in angular from C# .NET Web API. Here is what I am doing in my application:

**MVC Web API Model**

```
[Table("tblShirt")]
public class Shirt
{
    [Key]
    public int ShirtID { get; set; }
    public string ShirtName { get; set; }
    public string ShirtCode { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller Method for Angular to consume**

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IEnumerable<Shirt> GetShirtCodes()
{
    var result = (from r in db.Shirts where r.IsActive == true orderby r.ShirtCode select r).ToList();
    return (result);
}
```

**component.html**

```
<mat-form-field style="width:inherit;">
  <mat-label>Shirt Code</mat-label>
    <mat-select>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let shirt of shirts" [value]="shirts.value">
        {{shirts.viewValue}}
      </mat-option>
     </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

Beyond this I have mirrored my model in its own model.ts. This is where I am stuck. All the tutorials I have read go south from here. I have tried the following in my component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ReprintService } from 'src/app/shared/reprint.service';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Reprint } from 'src/app/shared/reprint.model';
import { NotificationService } from 'src/app/shared/notification.service';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material';

public GetShirtCodes = (): Observable<any> =>  
{  
    return this._http.get(this.actionUrl)  
        pipe.(map((response: Response) => <any>response.json())); //shows error on response
}
```

But I believe this is an outdated solution.

Comment: you need to declare a variable shirts:any in the ts file and assign it as shirts = GetShirtCodes () in the ngOnInt of the module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Component.html must be fixed this way:

```
<mat-form-field style="width:inherit;">
  <mat-label>Shirt Code</mat-label>
    <mat-select>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let shirt of shirts" [value]="shirt.ShirtID">
        {{shirt.ShirtName}}
      </mat-option>
     </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

For Service result must be set in your model:

general get :

```
  public Get<T>(endPoint: string, options?: IRequestOptions): Observable<T> {
    return this.http.get<T>(this.api + endPoint, options);
  }
```

less general get that call above service:

```
  getAll(endPoint: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient
      .Get(endPoint)
      .pipe(map(response => response));
  }
```

finally in your component:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.service.getAll(endPoint).subscribe(res => {this.shirts = res});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Being a beginner don't use `Observables` yet, try this out

```
this._someService.SearchSomeData(this._someId).
subscribe(x =>
{
    this.someInfo =x;
});
```

Your `someService` method may look like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class CoursesService {

constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

SearchSomeData(id, ){
    return this._http.get("/api/Search/GetSomeData/"+id );
}
```